# How to prevent edit or delete of some content by its author depending on an approval status field?

Tags: entities, rules, users

Here is a screenprint to illustrate part of my current implementation:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:

- If the value of 'Admin Status' is not "Approved", then the author can still edit or delete his/her own content.
- If the value of 'Admin Status' is "Approved", then the content can not be edited by the author.

I have tried a lot, even using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, but nothing works for me.

Any suggestions about how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module by using Event ***System > Drupal is initializing***, combined with a Rules Condition related to the URL for the *edit* or *delete* operation.

## Disallow edit

The rule you'd need for disallowing 'edit', is a variation of the rule I included (in export format) in my answer to the question about [How to restrict access to a node via node/12 and allow access via a path like content/sometitle?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165114/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-node-via-node-12-and-allow-access-via-a-path-like-co/165126#165126)

These are the changes to that rule to make it work this case also:

- The paths containing `node` should be extended by adding `/edit` at the end (I'm assuming that's how the URL for your edit link looks like).
- Add a (1st) Rules '*Condition*' like "If `Author id` matches the `uid`".
- Add a (2nd) Rules '*Condition*' like "If `Admin Status` is `Approved`".
- Change the "Message" (in the Rules '*Action*' to something to indicate that the edit is not allowed because `Admin Status` is `Approved`.
- Modify the Rules '*Action*' to fit your own requirements, e.g. to issue a redirect to some 'help page' with more details about this.

## Disallow delete

Should you also want to disallow 'delete' by the author for "Admin status" = 'Approved' (which is not what your question currently says however ...), then create another rule in which you use a similar approach as for 'edit' (as described above), just replace all 'edit' by 'delete'.

## Combine both rules

It should be possible to consolidate the 2 suggested rules above, using "OR" within Rules. Know however that this is a very little harder to get it to work. So learn to walk (= get it to work with 2 separated rules) before you want to learn to fly ...

## Video tutorials

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters.

**Note**: your question does not say what should happen (what is allowed or not) when a user who is not the author tries to edit or delete something with 'Admin Status' = Approved. If such scenario is possible in your setup, then you might have to further enhance the Rules Condition I suggested accordingly ...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is changing the content type of the node. A module that you could use to change content types at least manually would be [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert). However I don't know if this can also be triggered by the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) or [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) modules, or the like.

Anyways – changing the content type of a node would enable you to give permissions accordingly:

1. `content-type-not-approved` –> author ***can*** still edit
2. `content-type-approved` –> author ***can not*** edit any more