# How to disallow users to edit their content after it was submitted for review?

Tags: workflows, nodes, workbench

I'm looking for a solution that does not allow a user to edit content after being submitted for review.

I'm working with two roles: **Content Creator** and **Reviewer**.

If the Reviewer rejects the content, then it will be enabled for the Content Creator to apply changes again.

I've tried using the [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) module, it is very practical, but when the Content Creator submits a new content for review, the user still has access to edit this content, even if it is with status "*Under review*".

Answer (score 0):

You can look to the workflow module to implement a suitable workflow and permissions.

Comment: when suggesting a module, please include a link to that module, and a description of the module

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this (the only module you'd need ...), using an approach that is mostly similar to what I described in my answer to "[How to prevent edit or delete of some content by its author depending on an approval status field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156720/how-to-prevent-edit-or-delete-of-some-content-by-its-author-depending-on-an-appr/170357#170357)".

It would also take care of a variation of your question (if you'd want that), which is to take care of the situation that while the review is ongoing, you may not want to have it deleted either ...